# Linear functions with equal kernels.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For $\alpha, \beta \in V^*$ ($V^*$ - dual space) prove that in case of kernels equality: $ker\ \alpha = ker \ \beta$ the following is observed: $\exists~\lambda : \alpha = \lambda \cdot \beta$

I don't understand how that may happen, for example, if $\alpha = (1, 0, 3, 4)$ and $\beta = (2, 0, 5, 7)$, their kernels are equal, however they are not proportional by all means. It seems to me, that I haven't understood topic of dual spaces right, however can't find what I've missed in here.

Comment: If $V$ is a (finite dimensional) vector space over a field $k$ then $V^*$ is the $k$-vector space of linear maps $V \to k$. It seems you have taken $\alpha,\beta \in V$, but you want them in $V^*$ (assuming that $V$ is a vector space and all that).

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph And what is basis of $V^*$ then? (1,0... 0), (0,1,0,...0), (0,...,0, 1)? The question is, how I may represent $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then? As (1 by n) Matrices? And if so, what should $a_i$ be to make $e_i$ part of $\alpha$ kernel? I've considered, that if $a_i=0$ then $e_i$ is part of $\alpha$ kernel basis, am I right?)

Comment: $(3,0,-1,0)$ is in the kernel of $\alpha$, but not of $\beta$, no?

Comment: @9cloudalpha If $V$ has basis $(e_i)$, then $V^*$ can be given the basis basis $e_j^*$ defined on the $e_i$ as $e_j^*(e_i) = \delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker delta).

Comment: Remember, the kernel of an element of $V^*$ is going to have dimension $\dim(V) -1$. In the case of your $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you've noticed that their kernels both contain the vector $(0,1,0,0)$, but as GerryMyerson points out, their kernels are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N(\alpha) = N(\beta)$, there are two possibilities: either $N(\alpha) = N(\beta) = V$, in which case $R(\alpha) = R(\beta) = \{0\}$, that is to say, both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the null functionals from $V$ to $\textbf{F}$; or $N(\alpha) = N(\beta)$ and they have dimension $n-1$. Let, for instance, $\{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$ be a basis for $N(\alpha)$. Then we can extend it to a basis of $V$.

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$ be a basis for $V$ and $\mathcal{B}^{*} = \{f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n}\}$ be the basis for $V^{*}$ where $f_{i}(v_{j}) = \delta_{ij}$. Therefore $\alpha = \alpha(v_{1})f_{1} + \alpha(v_{2})f_{2} + \ldots + \alpha(v_{n})f_{n}$ and $\beta = \beta(v_{1})f_{1} + \beta(v_{2})f_{2} + \ldots + \beta(v_{n})f_{n}$. Hence we have that $\alpha(v) = \alpha(v_{n})f_{n}$ and $\beta(v) = \beta(v_{n})f_{n}$, where $\alpha(v_{n})\beta(v_{n})\neq 0$, because $\alpha(v_{n})$ spans $R(\alpha)$ and $\beta(v_{n})$ spans $R(\beta)$ and $\dim R(\alpha) = \dim R(\beta) = 1$.

Based on such considerations, we conclude that $\alpha = \lambda \beta$, where $\lambda\in\textbf{F}$ in the first case and $\lambda = \beta(v_{n})/\alpha(v_{n})$ in the second case. Such considerations result from the application of the following theorem (valid when $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional):
\begin{align*}
\dim V = \dim N(T) + \dim R(T)
\end{align*}

where $T$ is a linear mapping from the linear space $V$ to the linear space $W$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Here R stands for range and N for null-space of linear transformation?

Comment: Yes, that is it.